# How to approach 'caching' in iOS development with Swift

Tags: ios, caching, core-data, swift3, nscache

I am facing some issues in terms of what caching mechanism to implement for my iOS application. First, lets explain my situation.

I want to request thousands of nearby locations records (10000 and more) through a RESTful API on my server using **Alamofire**, where each record consists of a bunch of strings. The JSON response format looks similar to this:

```
[
   {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Name x",
     "lat": 59.5025878,
     "lng": -0.1509515,
     "address": "Address x"
   },
   {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "Name y",
     "lat": 61.5025878,
     "lng": -0.1508515,
     "address": "Address y"
   },

   etc.

 ]
```

The key is that I only want to send/resend this query when the application launches or after a certain amount of time has passed or when the app user moved his/her location considerably that it would also change the nearby locations. In order to keep the server load low I am planning to do search queries on returned locations inside the app instead of querying the server for every single request, which would be really inefficient and costly.

As a result, I want to cache my response data on the phone but I don't know what option to go with. I did some background reading on both **CoreData** and **NSCache**. CoreData would allow me to store the location results in a database. This has the benefit that stored records stay alive internally, since it is a permanent storage solution after all. On the other side, using CoreData might be a complete overkill as it comes with an overhead and keeping the location records in cache using **NSCache** would probably not use much memory (remember I am storing just strings). But then again, why keeping location data in the cache, when user might not even access them that often. Also, there is the chance that location entries in the cache will be freed up to save up more memory.

I am sure there are other solutions out there that might even be better suited for my purpose. After all, I am quite new to this topic in iOS, hence I would really appreciate some guidance.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are already several pods for this, such as https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift https://github.com/aschuch/AwesomeCache https://github.com/hyperoslo/Cache

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are on the right track with considering CoreData and NSCache.

There will be tradeoffs. In reducing your network activity, you will be looking to utilize device memory and/or the file system. Usage of any of these resources should be carefully considered. All of the options below are viable and it may be worthwhile to do some measuring with instruments to see the impact of each approach.

On paper here is how I would weigh them given your requirements.

### NSCache

**Pros**

- Simple API, low effort to implement
- Easy to reason about

**Cons**

- If the data that you need is no longer cached then you will have to fire another network request. That said, you could implement the NSCacheDelegate and respond when an “object is about to be evicted or removed from the cache.” see [NSCacheDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscachedelegate)

### Core Data

**Pros**

- Can be used as an in-memory store (not just for persisting data to
  disk)
- Can scale to accommodate more complex data modelling, querying and
  storage requirements
- Has Xcode tooling support

**Cons**

- Initially it would require more effort to implement than the other options
- As mentioned by Duncan C, there is a learning curve
- Adds another abstraction that may require more thought down the road than either the NSCache or plist

### File System (plist or some other format)

**Pros**

- Low effort to implement
- Easy to reason about

**Cons**

- Introduces file system I/O operations. From a performance standpoint this is not desirable if there are other options.
- Doesn’t easily scale (if your needs change)

Comment: nice comprehensive answer.

Comment: It means NSCache loses data when the app is terminated ... on other hand, Plist and CoreData keep the data

Comment: Just to help future readers, a point to note is that a straightforward implementation of NSCache would result in the cache being emptied when the app simply goes to background. Still trying to find a proper way around this behaviour

Answer (score 6):

What you've shown is an array of dictionaries.

If the data you are caching doesn't change that much, and when it changes the whole thing changes then you don't really need an SQL database.

You could simply save your array to a plist file using the `NSArray` method `func write(toFile:atomically:)`

If you write the array to the documents directory then it won't go away. If you write it to the caches directory then it could be flushed at a later time.

It has the advantage of being dirt-simple. It has the disadvantage that it doesn't lend itself to updating some contents and not others. You save the whole thing, and then you load the whole thing. Loading the whole thing into memory is not a big deal for 10,000 text-only records. If it's 250 bytes each, that's a little less than 2.5 MB - quite reasonable.

Core Data is very powerful, but also very complex, and has a steep learning curve. It takes a while to wrap your head around how to use it.